# Set X Axis Range on Plotly Frequency Graph

Tags: r, plotly, frequency

Consider the following graph:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10)
y <- as.data.frame(table(x))

y %>%
plot_ly(x = ~ x,
        y = ~ Freq,
        type = 'bar')
```

[image: Frequency Graph]

I would like to take this graph and produce a similar graph in which the values 7 and 9 are listed with a frequency of zero. Is there a way to get a frequency count of a sequence like `seq(0, 10, 1)` where 7 and 9 would appear as a frequency of 0 or is there a way that I can set the x axis on my plotly graph to be from 0 to 10 even though I don't have all the numbers in my data?

I have tried

```
y %>%
plot_ly(x = ~ x,
        y = ~ Freq,
        type = 'bar') %>%
layout(xaxis = list(autotick = FALSE, tick0 = 0, tickd = seq(0, 10, 1))
```

and also

```
layout(xaxis = list(autotick = FALSE, tick0 = 0, tickd = c(0,10))
```

but neither one seems to change anything.

I would like my desired output to look like this:

[image: Desired Output]

Note that This is just a small sample and my actual data will be much larger. Because of this, something like looping through the data and counting every number would be too slow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution is to convert `x` as a factor with levels from 1 to 10.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

x <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10)
x <- factor(x, levels=1:10)

y <- as.data.frame(table(x))

y %>%
plot_ly(x = ~ x,
        y = ~ Freq,
        type = 'bar')
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I couldn't think of that lol. Sometimes I overthink things.